# styling text at the end of polyline path (leaflet)

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

i create routing webgis that show multiply route from nearest facility function and 
i want to show the distance route using with [markinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPathplugin](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath) , but it's overlapping in the begining of route

[image]

i think it's better to place the text at the end of path. but idont know how to make it
here is the code for my styling:

```
function addDistanceText(Feature, layer) {
            layer.setText(Feature.properties.distance_route + 'km', {offset: 17 });
            }
```

here is geojson data:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[110.2382587,-7.9579805],[110.2380463,-7.9581418]]]},"properties":{"distance":"3989.57671272009"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[110.2374145,-7.9593029],[110.2371966,-7.9598229]]]},"properties":{"distance":"2206.76527447351"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[110.2374145,-7.9593029],[110.2379765,-7.9594952]]]},"properties":{"distance":"2667.74036482918"}}]}
```

any body know how to style text path without overlapping?

Comment: Reverse the polyline.

Comment: good point, where it sould be editted? plugin code?

Comment: Wherever you fetch or display it.

Comment: In your code you have an array of coords that is drawing the polyline. In order to reverse the polyline reverse the array for example with array.reverse();

Answer (score -1):

as IvanSanchez and enxaneta recomended, i reverse the geojson array (spesificlly the order of feature) 
here is the code:

```
result.features.forEach((feature) => {
   feature.geometry.coordinates.reverse().forEach(_reversecoordinate);
   function _reversecoordinate(item) {
      item.reverse();}
   });
```